# Add/remove subview and constraints in UITableViewCell on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that I'm using to show an array of custom objects.  Each object has several properties including a Boolean property that indicates if this item is new or not.

My `UITableViewCell` content view is defined in the storyboard and has an initial layout similar to this:

[image]

In my `UITableViewController`, when I dequeue my cells, I call a method on my `UITableViewCell` that configures the data to be displayed in the cell before I return it.  One of the properties that I check is the .isNew property that I mentioned previously.  If this value is true, then I am creating a `UIButton` and inserting it as a subview in the cell's content view so I end up with something like this:

[image]

Just for context, this button will show a "new" image to indicate that this item is new.  I am also hooking up a method that will fire when the button is tapped.  That method is also defined in my `UITableViewCell` and looks like this:

```
@objc func newIndicatorButtonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
   // call delegate method and pass this cell as the argument
   delegate?.newIndicatorButtonTapped(cell: self)
}
```

I have also created a protocol that defines a delegate method.  My `UITableViewController` conforms to this and I see that code fire when I tap on the button in my cell(s).  Here's is the delegate method (defined in an extension on my `UITableViewController`):

```
func newIndicatorButtonTapped(cell: UITableViewCell) {        
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

I see the row from the `indexPath` print out correctly in Xcode when I tap on the cell.  When my user taps on this button, I need to remove it (the button) and update the constraint for my `UILabel` so that is aligned again with the leading edge of the content view as shown in the first mockup above.  Unfortunately, I seem to be running into an issue with cell recycling because the `UIButton` is disappearing and re-appearing in different cells as I scroll through them.  Do I need to reset the cell's layout/appearance before it gets recycled or am I misunderstanding something about how cell recycling works?  Any tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may be thinking is that you get a "fresh" cell, but when a cell gets *re-cycled* that means it gets ***re-used***.

You can see this very easily by changing the text color of a basic cell.

For example:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyID", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

    if indexPath.row == 3 {
        cell.theLabel.textColor = .red
    }

    return cell
}
```

As you would expect, when the table first loads the text color will change for the 4th row (row indexing is zero-based).

However, suppose you have 100 rows? As you scroll, the cells will be *re-used* ... and each time that original-4th-cell gets re-used, it will still have red text.

So, as you guessed, yes... you need to "reset" your cell to its original layout / content / colors / etc each time you want to use it:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyID", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

    if indexPath.row == 3 {
        cell.theLabel.textColor = .red
    } else {
        cell.theLabel.textColor = .black
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider to have the button hidden and then change the layout when it is clicked.

[image]

Firing the action from the cell to the tableView with a protocol and then reseting the layout at cell reuse is a good way to do it

Doing it in a cell fully programatic would be like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.isNew = indexPath.row == 0 ? true : false
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
}
```

And the cell class needs to be similar to: (you can do what you need by changing the Autolayout constraint, manipulating the frame directly or using a UIStackView)

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    var isNew: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if isNew {
                button.isHidden = true
                leftConstraint.constant = 20
            } else {
                button.isHidden = false
                leftConstraint.constant = 100
            }                    
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    var button: UIButton!
    var label: UILabel!
    var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Click", for: .normal)
        self.contentView.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
        button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

        label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Label"
        self.contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        leftConstraint = label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 100)
        leftConstraint.isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```